# How could i generate a well-formatted word file (.DOC) using python?

Tags: python

I would like to generate a word file using python that has all the formatting generated by MS Word.

Please suggest any python modules that can help me achieve this.

Code tried for example:

Downloaded pywin32-218.win32-py2.7 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/ for import win32com.client and trying following example. But it is giving me error as **IndexError: list index out of range in  sFileName  = sys.argv[1]**

```
import sys
import time
import string
import win32com.client

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
class CWordAutomate:
    """Encapsulates a winword com connection"""
    def __init__( self ):
        """construct: create OLE connection to winword"""
        self.m_obWord         = win32com.client.Dispatch( "Word.Application" )
        self.m_obDoc          = self.m_obWord.Documents.Add( ) # create new doc
        self.m_obWord.Visible = 1
        self.m_Sel            = self.m_obWord.Selection # get a selection

    def WriteLine( self, sTxt, sFont, lSize, bBold=0 ):
        """Write a line to winword"""
        self.m_Sel.Font.Name = sFont
        self.m_Sel.Font.Bold = bBold
        self.m_Sel.Font.Size = lSize
        self.m_Sel.TypeText( Text=sTxt + "\n"  )

# --------------------------------------------------------------------

# - open a file
sFileName  = sys.argv[1]
obFile     = file( sFileName, 'r+' )
sContent   = obFile.read()
obFile.close()
lstContent = sContent.splitlines()

# - display contents in word
obWord = CWordAutomate()
obWord.WriteLine( "Content of the file " + sFileName, "Times New Roman", 18, 1 )
for sLine in lstContent:
    obWord.WriteLine( sLine, "Courier New", 10  )
sLastMsg = time.strftime( "document generated on %c", time.localtime()  )
obWord.WriteLine( sLastMsg, "Times New Roman", 14, 0 )
```

Comment: [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is something new for me so I google it and asked here.

Comment: ok yes. I will make sure next time. Thank you

Comment: Answer is : winapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application"),
windoc = winapp.Documents.Add()

Comment: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx This Solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not go for ".doc" files, but rather create ".rtf" or ".docx" files depending on your requirements. ".docx" files are quite well defined (a couple thousand pages or so somewhere on the Microsoft.com web site), if you really want to create it by hand.

Or you can create one yourself in Word, put some placeholders into it, parse the file with Python (it's a zip file after all), use lxml or a similar XML package for modiying the contents and save it under a different name.

There is a nice page which talks about this: http://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/

Comment: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx this solve my problem thanks